# nodejs 3des decrypt didn't get expected result

Tags: node.js, encryption, 3des

My nodejs 3DES decryption didn't get expected result. Is there anything wrong with my code?

```
let cryptojs = require('crypto-js')
var key = '551408C3D129EC64DA505CB48CD61D57551408C3D129EC64';
var ciphertext = 'C5F21F0F82038833851BA3092D613F085A60DB1E189E10F6';
var iv = cryptojs.enc.Hex.parse("0".repeat(16));

key = cryptojs.enc.Hex.parse(key);
var result = cryptojs.TripleDES.decrypt(ciphertext, key, {iv: iv, mode: cryptojs.mode.CBC, padding: cryptojs.pad.NoPadding});
console.log ('decrypted ' + result.toString(cryptojs.enc.Hex));
```

result is '90d49e1085d5251f87dbcd6292570ba30e8a6e0f84d8331c97a579ef0ba6ac867342f2f6'

however expected result should be '466F0198321458864627662057083A457601185220050000'

Comment: Encrypt or decrypt?  Please clarify and edit your question.

Comment: sorry for the type during copy and paste, i just updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some more testing found out need to add one more line of code before decrypt :

```
ciphertext = cryptojs.format.Hex.parse(ciphertext);
```

complete code as below :

```
let cryptojs = require('crypto-js')
var key = '551408C3D129EC64DA505CB48CD61D57551408C3D129EC64';
var ciphertext = 'C5F21F0F82038833851BA3092D613F085A60DB1E189E10F6';
var iv = cryptojs.enc.Hex.parse("0".repeat(16));

key = cryptojs.enc.Hex.parse(key);
ciphertext = cryptojs.format.Hex.parse(ciphertext);
var result = cryptojs.TripleDES.decrypt(ciphertext, key, {iv: iv, mode: cryptojs.mode.CBC, padding: cryptojs.pad.NoPadding});
console.log ('decrypted ' + result.toString(cryptojs.enc.Hex));
```

result is

```
decrypted 466f0198321458864627662057083a457601185220050000
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you were trying to decrypt the data, but you encrypted it:

```
var result = cryptojs.TripleDES.encrypt(ciphertext, key, {iv: iv, mode: cryptojs.mode.CBC, padding: cryptojs.pad.NoPadding});
```

Comment: sorry for the typo during the copy and paste, i still not get expected even it change to decrypt

Comment: You've likely forgotten to call Hex.parse on the ciphertext.

Comment: tested ciphertext = cryptojs.enc.Hex.parse(ciphertext); before decrypt, result become empty : "WordArray.init {words: Array(0), sigBytes: 0}"

Comment: after more testing,  Hex.parse needed but need use format.Hex.parse instead of enc.Hex.parse -_-; .......